# WCF - way of using data contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, model, datacontract

If I have a **core class** which is used internally by all the modules and then I would like to publish a *wcf service* which would make use of this class... then what is the best way to do that? Is it better *to mark it as data contract* directly, or better *create a new class as data contract* which either inherits or maps to the core structure or ... what do you suggest guys?

Comment: I also found this question related to this one which helps other people coming to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83604/wcf-datacontracts-and-underlying-data-structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either will work, since in most cases the client will be getting a WSDL/MEX representation - not your type directly. In either case, remember to use explicit `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember]` attributes so that it truly is *contract-based*, rather than looking at the fields.

(note: don't *inherit* a DTO from your domain type; a DTO should be separate, if you go that route)

Personally, I prefer a separate DTO, but I know people have success exposing the domain model directly (that is how LINQ-to-Data-Services works, for example).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. So, if both would work, which one would be better? What if I would come up with a second service which would make use of the same class, but slightly different?

Comment: @Cristi - in that case, separate DTOs. Without the additional context of second service", either is honestly workable. I prefer separate DTOs, but it is a but subjective until you have a specific requirement to push it one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc. You've been very helpful. Before I close this question could you please check this question that I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913177/wcf-multiple-service-contracts-using-pretty-same-data-contracts . Here everybody says that I should use inheritance and I was pretty sure that I should not do that. It's pretty close to this question, so please, if you have time and want to help. I just want to be sure that I go in the right direction.

Comment: Actually that is really kind of a concrete case with 2 different services using a core class.

Comment: @Cristi - wow, I hate that; very little isolation etc. Up to you of course.

Comment: Yeah, personally i really think creating new data contracts which maps from/into the core classes would give higher flexibility and decoupling... so maybe I should stick to this.